# Android how to hide the table lyout

Tags: java, android, tablerow

In my android application a love compatibility test is doing.. where first the details of boys and then details of girls are entered in the same page..one after another. and separate save button for saving boy details and girl details and these data is saved in separate databases. and there is a recall button also there for both boys and girls. When this recall button is pressed the database will opened and from that user can select the name to be checked. When he press the corresponding data has to be entered into the corresponding edittexts. In my case I don't know how to close this tablerow. that mean the database opened.then only the data will go to the corresponding edittext box.

I am giving my code below

**MainActivity**

```
btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Cursor c = dbb.rawQuery("SELECT * from Data3", null);
            int count = c.getCount();
            c.moveToFirst();




            TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
            tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
            TableRow tableRow;
            TextView textView1, textView2,textView3, textView4, textView5, textView6, textView7, textView8 ;
            tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());         
            textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView1.setText("First Name");
            textView1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            textView1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            textView1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            tableRow.addView(textView1);

            textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView2.setText("Last Name");
            textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            textView2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            textView2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            tableRow.addView(textView2);

            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);


            for(Integer j=0; j<count; j++)              
            {

                tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

                textView3= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ffirstname")));
                textView3.setClickable(true);
                ett1=textView3.getText().toString();

                textView4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView4.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fmiddlename")));
                textView4.setClickable(true);
                ett2=textView4.getText().toString();


                textView5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("flastname")));
                textView5.setClickable(true);
                ett3=textView5.getText().toString();


                textView6 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView6.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fdayofbirth")));
                textView6.setClickable(true);
                ett4=textView6.getText().toString();


                textView7 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView7.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fmonthofbirth")));
                textView7.setClickable(true);
                ett5=textView7.getText().toString();

                textView8 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                textView8.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fyearofbirth")));
                textView8.setClickable(true);
                ett6=textView8.getText().toString();


                textView3.setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);
                textView5.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tableRow.addView(textView3);
                tableRow.addView(textView5);
                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                c.moveToNext();

                final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(textView3.getText().toString());
                list.add(textView4.getText().toString());
                list.add(textView5.getText().toString());         
                list.add(textView6.getText().toString());
                list.add(textView7.getText().toString());         
                list.add(textView8.getText().toString());


                textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                           
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    }
                });



            }

            c.close();
            setContentView(tableLayout);
              dbb.close();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try this tablelayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); or tablelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I already tried this but at that time what will happen is ... this tablerow will go invisible .. but the whitespace will remain.. that means I am getting a white screen. not the edittext page

Comment: are u tried gone or invisible which one?

Comment: Both time .. whitespace is coming

Comment: anybody here to help me

Answer (score 0):

**Declare the table layout out side button click** and to make it GONE/INVISIBLE do Like this

```
 tablelayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//white space will be available
```

Or

```
 tablelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);//No white space
```